# Can somebody explain why line break works only sometimes in api whatsapp?

Tags: encoding, line-breaks, whatsapp

Can you please explain why these line breaks work on phone, but not on desktop browser (whatsapp web)?

https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=foo%0Abar

But actually, line breaks sometimes work on browser:

https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=Lorem%2520ipsum%2520dolor%2520sit%2520amet%0ADuis%2520imperdiet%2520in%2520ligula%2520eu%2520scelerisq

(We have to be reaaaaally tricky about the encoding when using desktop)

## Context

I'm using whatsapp kinda Whatsapp "api" to send messages from my webapp. In theory, they say line breaks can be sent via `%0A` but testing from the desktop we have to do this process:

- Take the multiline string and encode it.
- Take the encoded string, and replace all instances of `%0A` with real linebreaks (`/n`)
- Encode that string (again).

And even sometimes that does not work. The lines have to have some length and amount of words for it to work.